# Debian which repository has the package autossh?

Tags: debian, repository, autossh

I am trying to install `autossh` on Debian squeeze, but I am getting error `E: Unable to locate package autossh`.

I don't know which repository the package `autossh` is present in. I tried [searching on the Debian site](https://search.debian.org/cgi-bin/omega?DB=en&P=autossh) but couldn't get the repository address.

So, where is this package? What repo address to add to the apt sources.list?

Edit:

Here is my `sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
```

On
    `apt-cache policy autossh`

I get the error

```
N: Unable to locate package autossh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `autossh` package isn't available on debian [squeeze](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/allpackages) (EOL), you should build the package :

```
git clone https://github.com/leiqin/obfuscated-autossh.git
cd obfuscated-autossh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I have the `main` repo in my list. Edited my question to add output of `apt-cache`. I have `squeeze` but your answer is about `jessie`.